# algorithm, translate this statement into an algorithm

Tags: logic, algorithms

How can I translate this statement below into an algorithm. thanks.

- If the car reaches the edge of the wall on the east OR on the West
  side
- the car goes backwards a short distance
- then, the car turns to a random direction AND go forward
- If the car reaches the edge of the wall on the North OR on the south
  side
- the car goes backwards a short distance, then
- then,the car turns to a random direction AND go forward

Comment: it is already an algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know quite what you mean by algorithm, so here is some pseudo-code.

if (car reaches the edge of the wall on the east OR on the West side)

```
 move backward a short distance.
 turn random direction.
 go forward.
```

endif

if (car reaches the edge of the wall on the north OR on the south side)

```
 move backward a short distance.
 turn random direction.
 go forward.
```

endif

The above algorithm matches what you described, but the following algorithm is more compact, and I beleive it does the same thing.

if (car reaches the edge of the wall on ANY side)

```
 move backward a short distance.
 turn random direction.
 go forward.
```

endif

Comment: I am not sure but when it says algorithm, i think it's something like, let's suppose that x=car, y=width 0 as west to 10 as east, so  if (x> 10y ll x < y), same as if (car reaches the edge of the wall on the east OR on the West side).